# check if value is in an array list javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I want to check if there is an array that exists in my_array_list where 'a' = 1 and 'b' = 2, and if it exists, return the index.

```
my_array_list = [{ 'a' : 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3}]
```

Code structure that doesn't work:

```
var a = 1
var b = 2

if (a in my_array_list and b in my_array_list){
    print (index)
}
```

Comment: Please check and approve the answer

Answer (score 4):

Use `array.find`

```js
my_array_list = [{ 'a' : 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3}];

const node = my_array_list.find(node => node.a === 1 && node.b ===2);

const index = my_array_list.indexOf(node);

console.log(node, index);
```

If you are not intersted in finding the node you can use `array.findIndex` directly.

```js
my_array_list = [{ 'a' : 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3}];

const index = my_array_list.findIndex(node => node.a === 1 && node.b ===2);

console.log(index);
```

Comment: findIndex i think best option because it give result in one line instead of first find value then go for index

Comment: If the user is not intended to find the node, then he can opt this.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution

Right now in your array b=2 is two times so it pick index of first b=2

```js
var my_array_list = [{ 'a' : 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3}]

  
  
    
var index = my_array_list.findIndex(x => x.a ===1);
var index2 = my_array_list.findIndex(x => x.b ===2);


console.log("index of a=1",index);
console.log("index of b=2",index2);
```

Comment: it should be`my_array_list.findIndex(x => x.a === 1 && x.b ===2);`

Comment: Yeah it can be, but if someone want to find separately then this solution for them

Answer (score 0):

```js
const my_array_list = [
  { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3},
  { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3},
  { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3}
]

const findIndex = (arr, valA, valB) => {
  for (const i in arr) {
    const { a, b } = arr[i]
    if (a === valA && b === valB) return Number(i)
  }

  // Didn't find
  return -1
}

const index = findIndex(my_array_list, 1, 2)
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
my_array_list = [{ 'a' : 5, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3}, { 'a' : 5, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3}];
var a = 1
var b = 2
var obj = my_array_list.find(x => x.a === a && x.b ===b);
var index = my_array_list.indexOf(obj );
console.log(index);
```